# How to make a drop-in replacement in Java

Tags: java, casting

I want to add new methods to the java.awt.Rectangle class. If I were using Objective-C, then I could use a category. Or if I were using C++ I could make a new class MyRectangle and define a constructor/cast pair so that it is a drop-in replacement.

For example, in C++

```
struct java_awt_Rectangle { int x,y,w,h; };    // a dummy for illustration

class MyRectangle                      // a drop in replacement for Rectangle
{
    java_awt_Rectangle rect;

public:
    MyRectangle() {}
    MyRectangle(const java_awt_Rectangle& r) {}

    operator java_awt_Rectangle& ()
    {
        return rect;
    }
};


int main()
{
    java_awt_Rectangle t;
    MyRectangle m;
    m = t;
    t = m;
}
```

Is anything like this possible in Java?  I tried making a class in Java

```
public class MyRectangle extends java.awt.Rectangle
{
    public MyRectangle(java.awt.Rectangle r)
    {
        super(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, because in Java the constructor is not used for implicit conversion (like it is in other languages).

**EDIT:** notice in the C++ example I get implicit conversion in *both* directions. That is my goal.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your MyRectangle class looks fine, assuming you intend to create a new instance of MyRectangle based on the passed java.awt.Rectangle instance.

Comment: Bloch, Item 16: "Favor composition over inheritance" might offer some useful tips.

Comment: @Eran It doesn't work because I get error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.awt.Rectangle to MyRectangle. The goal is for MyRectangle to be a drop in replacement for Rectangle.

Comment: @JohnHenckel Are you trying to cast a Rectangle to MyRectangle and expect your constructor to be used? That doesn't work. You can do the conversion yourself : `MyRectangle myrect = new MyRectangle(rect);` where `rect` is a `Rectangle`.

Comment: @Eran Post it as an answer

Comment: @Eran Yes, that is my goal. I was hoping to not clutter my code with "new MyRectangle" everywhere. That is what I mean by "drop in replacement"

Comment: @rossum I agree that composition is better, such as I used in the C++ example. However the lack of cast operators in Java means that I have to use inheritance (in order to get automatic conversion from MyRectangle to java.awt.Rectangle). I guess Java really doesn't like implicit type conversions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reverse direction just won't work with inheritance. You can pass `MyRectangle` to a method/field expecting `Rectangle` but never the other way around. You can use composition to get around this in some (but not all) cases.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the designers of the Java language felt that implicit conversions are hazardous or confusing, so they did not include any mechanism for it, other than a few primitive types (int -> double, etc) and downcasting.

The cleanest way to add some utilities to the Rectangle class is to write your own static-only utils, for instance

```
public class MyUtils
{
    public static Point getCenter(Rectangle r) {}
}
```

Comment: Whether this is the cleanest way depends on the situation. Well-designed classes can be extended in more flexible ways. Unfortunately, `java.awt.Rectangle` is amongst the worst classes in the entire class library, with all its fields exposed.

Comment: Agree Rectangle is horrible. And the Java language offers no mechanism to avoid using horrible classes. This is the feature I miss the most from C++. In C++, using a constructor and cast operator, I can get implicit conversion in both directions.

Comment: On the other hand, it's equally horrible for everyone. If you see a `String`, that's the same `String` in everyone's code. Same with operator overloading: if you see a `+`, that's definitely an addition of two numbers and not something else. (Unless it's string concatenation because ... well, just because.) But the principle is to provide a common base that you can trust without having to trace every single call in case someone dropped in a replacement class. With AWT you can also trust classes being awful.